# Magento paginate not displayed on homepage

Tags: php, magento

I follow this tutorial http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination to display the newest products. 
All work perfect, toolbar is displayed, paginate work good (I checked adding manually at the end of the link this: "?p=2").

So, the problem/question is: what is the reason does not display pages?

[image: I put a printscreen to see what happens]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Just add this in "Layout Update XML":

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>
</reference>
```